# Zoom and Pan controls simultaneously for a custom Winforms designer control

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, drawing, gdi

I am trying to make a 'designer' in winforms. This will present a wysiwyg 'Canvas' to the user onto which they can drop images, text and shapes. They can then select, move and resize them via a "Selector" box with handles. The user can also select more than one object at a time, therefore, multiple selectors are necessary. You must also be able to zoom and pan the Canvas.

It has to be through winforms. The approach I've decided on is to procedurally draw all items onto a single control (a `PicturBox` as the Canvas) in the `Paint` event. For the Selectors, I'll use a control placed on top of the Canvas as a guide for the corners of the drag handles. I'll then make this control invisible.

I have made a custom `PictureBox`(`ScaledPictureBox`) which is scalable and placed this inside of a `Panel` with autoscroll enabled. This works well - with zoom and pan implemented. I have then placed another `ScaledPictureBox` on top of this as the Selector.

The code below works just fine for panning both at 100%. However, when I pan when it is zoomed, the location of the Selector is off. Here's a vid:

[Video](https://youtu.be/lifUqmjCMtk)

Here's the code:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Partial Public Class ScaledPictureBox
    Inherits PictureBox

    Public Property ScaleM As Matrix
    Private Property Zoom As Single
    Private Property OriginalSize As Size

    Public Sub New()
        ScaleM = New Matrix()
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
    End Sub

    Public Sub InitImage()
        OriginalSize = Me.Size
        Size = OriginalSize
        SetZoom(100)
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetZoom(ByVal zoomfactor As Single)
        If zoomfactor <= 0 Then Throw New Exception("Zoom must be positive")
        Dim oldZoom As Single = Zoom
        Zoom = zoomfactor / 100.0F
        ScaleM.Reset()
        ScaleM.Scale(Zoom, Zoom)
        If OriginalSize <> Size.Empty Then Size = New Size(CInt((OriginalSize.Width * Zoom)), CInt((OriginalSize.Height * Zoom)))
    End Sub

    Public Function ScalePoint(ByVal pt As PointF) As PointF
        Return New PointF(pt.X / Zoom, pt.Y / Zoom)
    End Function

End Class
```

Test form:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Canvas.InitImage()
        Selector.InitImage()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll

        Canvas.SetZoom(CInt(TrackBar1.Value))
        Selector.SetZoom(CInt(TrackBar1.Value))

        Canvas.Invalidate()
        Selector.Invalidate()

    End Sub

    Dim moving As Boolean = False
    Dim CanvasClickPoint As New Point
    Dim SelectorLocation As New Point

    Private Sub Canvas_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Canvas.MouseDown

        If (ModifierKeys And Keys.Control) = Keys.Control Then
            moving = True
            CanvasClickPoint = e.Location
            SelectorLocation = Selector.Location
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Canvas_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Canvas.MouseMove

        If moving Then

            Dim CanvasNewPoint As Point = New Point(Canvas.Left + (e.Location.X - CanvasClickPoint.X),
                                                      Canvas.Top + (e.Location.Y - CanvasClickPoint.Y))

            SelectorLocation.X = SelectorLocation.X + (e.Location.X - CanvasClickPoint.X)
            SelectorLocation.Y = SelectorLocation.Y + (e.Location.Y - CanvasClickPoint.Y)

            Dim SelectorLocationPointf As PointF = SelectorLocation
            SelectorLocation = Point.Round(Selector.ScalePoint(SelectorLocationPointf))
            Selector.Location = SelectorLocation

            Canvas.Location = CanvasNewPoint

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Canvas_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Canvas.MouseUp
        moving = False
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here's the test setup of controls locations to frame discussion:

[image]

I'm guessing this has to do with my use of `Selector.ScalePoint` - the Selector's position will need some scaling applied, as if you don't, it is off for anything other than 100% scale. However, the maths and technique is beyond me, as I lifted the code for the `ScaledPictureBox` and whilst I can broadly understand the ides behind `ScalePoint` I can't quite get my head around it. Hope someone can help

Download of Visual Studio Project (small) [HERE](https://niftymonkey.uk/hpserverpublic/Documents/VS%20Projects/WinformsCanvas.7z)

Comment: Why don't you simply resize the PictureBoxes (in `SizeMode = Zoom`, for sure you don't want to stretch your images, right?) based on the selected scale? It's no clear what is the initial size of the PictureBox and what determines it. The other PictureBox (whatever that's for) can have an initial size that is always the same or scaled on the initial size of the larger Control. The parent the smaller PictureBox to the larger one, so when you move the image, the smaller PicureBox follows its Parent and there's nothing else to do. -- I suggest to build an UserControl with the two controls.

Comment: Thanks. `ScaledPictureBox` does resize the PictureBox. I'm pretty sure what you're suggesting it what it does anyway. The issue is with the zoom routine.

Comment: I'm suggesting to **only** scale the Size of the PictureBoxes. I'm saying that because you mentioned *drawing*  and there's a Matrix there, even though nothing is drawn anywhere in the code you posted and the use of the Matrix is unknown. -- When you parent your scaled `Selector` to the larger PictureBox, there's no need to move it in code when the other PictureBox is moved, since it's parented to it and will follow without any further calculation. -- Also mentioned, you should build an UserControl that contains the whole functionality.

Comment: @Jimi - perfect, thanks - I missed the fundamental. Parenting the Selector to the Canvas alongside some other code jiggles did the trick (working code posted below). Added bonus of it essentially providing a 'transparent control' that you also helped me with on another post. Onto another rewrite....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jimi, answer found. I'd missed that adding a control to a control in VS Designer doesn't necessarily make it a child of the parent. This in code alongside some other fixes got it working. ScalableControl:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Partial Public Class ScaledPictureBox
    Inherits PictureBox

    Public Property ScaleM As Matrix
    Private Property OriginalSize As Size
    Private Property Zoom As Single

    Public Sub New()
        ScaleM = New Matrix()
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
    End Sub

    Public Sub InitImage()
        OriginalSize = Me.Size
        Size = OriginalSize
        SetZoom(100)
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetZoom(ByVal zoomfactor As Single)
        If zoomfactor <= 0 Then Throw New Exception("Zoom must be positive")
        Dim oldZoom As Single = Zoom
        Zoom = zoomfactor / 100.0F
        ScaleM.Reset()
        ScaleM.Scale(Zoom, Zoom)
        If OriginalSize <> Size.Empty Then Size = New Size(CInt((OriginalSize.Width * Zoom)), CInt((OriginalSize.Height * Zoom)))
    End Sub

    Public Function ScalePoint(ByVal pt As PointF) As PointF
        Return New PointF(pt.X / Zoom, pt.Y / Zoom)
    End Function

End Class
```

And how to use:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim moving As Boolean = False
Dim CanvasClickPoint As New Point
Dim SelectorLocation As New Point

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Canvas.InitImage()
    Selector.InitImage()

    SelectorLocation = Selector.Location

    Canvas.Controls.Add(Selector)

End Sub

Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll

    Zoom(TrackBar1.Value)

End Sub

Private Sub Zoom(zoom As Integer)

    Canvas.SetZoom(CInt(zoom))
    Selector.SetZoom(CInt(zoom))

    Selector.Location = New Point(SelectorLocation.X * (zoom / 100), SelectorLocation.Y * (zoom / 100))

End Sub

Private Sub Canvas_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Canvas.MouseDown

    If (ModifierKeys And Keys.Control) = Keys.Control Then
        moving = True
        CanvasClickPoint = e.Location
        SelectorLocation = Point.Round(Canvas.ScalePoint(New PointF(Selector.Location.X, Selector.Location.Y)))
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Canvas_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Canvas.MouseMove

    If moving Then

        Dim CanvasNewPoint As Point = New Point(Canvas.Left + (e.Location.X - CanvasClickPoint.X),
                                                  Canvas.Top + (e.Location.Y - CanvasClickPoint.Y))

        Canvas.Location = CanvasNewPoint

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Canvas_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Canvas.MouseUp
    moving = False
    Canvas.Invalidate()
End Sub

End Class
```